# How to get the shape of a dataframe returned from a function

Tags: python, function, dataframe, tuples, typeerror

I am trying to return a dataframe from a function. When I try to check the shape of the returned dataframe, I get the below error.

*"TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable"*

The code I am running is as below

```
def fun():
    data1 = pd.DataFrame(data[(data['Date'] > start_Date)]
    return data1
data1.shape()
```

here start_Date is a variable having a date value.

I tried searching for a solution but couldn't find any. Would really appreciate any help over here

Regards,

Comment: `data1.shape` not `data1.shape()`

Answer (score 1):

`shape` is an attribute of the data frame, not a method.

Use :

```py
data1.shape
```